# Import bigquery_to_postgres on GCP Cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I would like to use BigQueryToPostgresOperator in my Composer Dag in GCP. I am getting:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery_to_postgres' from
> 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers'
> (/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/**init**.py)

I am importing:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers import bigquery_to_postgres
```

My composer environment:

```
composer-1.20.12-airflow-2.4.3
```

Comment: Have you installed [apache-airflow-providers-google](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html)?

Comment: I have listed all packages in composer instance. It has installed: apache-airflow-providers-google                  2023.4.13+composer

Answer (score 0):

The `BigQueryToPostgresOperator` was released in `apache-airflow-providers-google 10.1.0`

If you can upgrade your google provider please follow [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#managing-providers-separately-from-airflow-core) for best practices on how to upgrade. Once you have the newer version of the provider the import will work for you and you can use the operator.

If you can not upgrade your provider version for some reason then you can create a a copy of the operator in your local deployment based on the [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/30658) with the feature.
You will need to copy the code of `BigQueryToSqlBaseOperator` and `BigQueryToPostgresOperator` from the PR and place them in your deployment.
Then import the class and use it in your DAG. In the future once you upgrade your provider version you can simply delete the local copied code and change the imports to the open source class.